# Round a string column in java spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark, dataset

I have the below spark dataset.

```
Column_1
255678.05345
1111000.00002
```

It's a string column and I have to round the value to nearest ten thousands of the non decimal part and the output should be in decimal (10,2) format.

Expected output:

```
Column_1
260000.00
1110000.00
```

How to achieve this in spark. I tried using round() method but not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: you mean to say convert 255678 to 260000? and control decimal point also?

Comment: Yes. Decimal points will always be zero in output and I have to convert the main part to nearest value of 10000th place

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I tried to come you with the solution hoping it will work. Following sample code works fine in my databricks notebook

Step 1 Sample Data Creation

```
   %scala

   val df = spark.createDataFrame(
   Seq((0, 255678.05345), (1, 1111000.00002))
   ).toDF("id", "Salary")

   df.show()
```

Output:

```
    +---+-------------+
    | id|       Salary|
    +---+-------------+
    |  0| 255678.05345|
    |  1|1111000.00002|
    +---+-------------+
```

Step2: Implementing the logic using round

```
    %scala

    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.IntegerType

    df.withColumn("NewSalary", round(col("Salary")/ 1000000, 2) * 1000000).show()
```

Output:

```
    +---+-------------+---------+
    | id|       Salary|NewSalary|
    +---+-------------+---------+
    |  0| 255678.05345| 260000.0|
    |  1|1111000.00002|1110000.0|
    +---+-------------+---------+
```

Just incase if it is helpful please vote for it.